# UIView animateWithDuration: slows down animation frame rate

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview, nstimer

I am using `CADisplayLink` to draw frames using the `EAGLView` method in a game at 60 times per second.

When I call `UIView` `animateWithDuration:` the framerate drops down to exactly half, from 60 to 30 fps for the duration of the animation.  Once the animation is over, the fps rises instantly back up to 60.

I also tried using `NSTimer` animation method instead of `CADisplayLink` and still get the same result.

The same behavior happens when I press the volume buttons while the speaker icon is fading out, so it may be using `animateWithDuration`.  As I would like to be able to handle the speaker icon smoothly in my app, this means I can't just rewrite my animation code to use a different method other than `animateWithDuration`, but need to find a solution that works with it.

I am aware that there is an option to slow down animations for debug on the simulator, however, I am experiencing this on the device and no such option is enabled.  I also tried using various options for `animateWithDuration` such as the linear one and the user interaction, but none had an improvement.

I am also aware I can design an engine that can still work with a frame rate that varies widely.  However, this is not an ideal solution to this problem, as high fps is desirable for games.

Has someone seen this problem or solved it before?

Comment: Tried the volume button test on a GLKit-based app (based on the Xcode template, where a GLKViewController subclass does all the drawing for a GLKView) and noticed no slowdown. Maybe Apple's done some voodoo in GLKit that might help you? Either that or it's an iOS 6 thing; haven't tried this app on iOS 5.

Comment: @rickster thanks for that.  I can confirm this doesn't happen on my ios 6 ipad.  I guess this is just an apple bug that they fixed in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to do your own animation and blit during the CADisplayLink callback.

1) for the volume issue, put a small volume icon in the corner, or show it if the user takes some predefined touch action, and give them touch controls. With that input you can use AVAudioPlayer to vary the volume, and just avoid the system control altogether. you might even be able to determine the user has pressed the volume buttons, and pop some note saying do it your way. This gets you away from any animations happening by the system.

2) When you have an animation you want to do, well, create a series of images in code (either then or before hand), and every so many callbacks in the displayLink blit the image to the screen.

Comment: I think dealing with the animations internally is probably the way to go.  But, handling the volume buttons this way is still kind of unfriendly to the user, and there will still be the framerate drop when they do press them.  Also, if I use an internal mixer volume, won't this limit the max volume to whatever the system volume is set to, meaning the in-app volume display is inconsistent?

Comment: I don't know the answer to system volume / app volume - you'll have to do research. Its just a way around having them use the side buttons. When your app starts up you could even ask them to up the volume - in any case the volume they want for a game is probably not the same they want for phone ringer etc (well maybe it is). If you can do a little upfront work with them, get then to use onscreen volume - it will make your game more responsive The odds of you figuring a way to work around the system HUD is very low, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an old thread that describes similar drops in frame rate](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3507). In that case, the cause of the problem was adding two or more semi-transparent sprites, but I'd guess that any time you try to composite several layers together you may be doing enough work to cut the frame rate, and `animateWithDuration` very likely does exactly that kind of thing.

Answer (score -1):

Either use OpenGL or CoreAnimation. They are not compatible.

To test this remove any UIView animation, the frame rate will be what you expect.  Add back UIView animation, it will drop to 30fps.

You said:

> When I call UIView animateWithDuration: the framerate drops down to exactly half, from 60 to 30 fps for the duration of the animation. Once the animation is over, the fps rises instantly back up to 60

I dont know why your not accepting my answer, this is exactly what happens when you combine UIView animation with CA animation not using a UIView.

Comment: CADisplayLink works fine with OpenGL and is the basis for the EAGLView example that many use.  Also, since this drop happens when I touch the speaker volume buttons, this needs to be dealt with regardless.

Comment: its **not** a drop in framerate.  The docs for animation clearly state that UIView animation is locked at 30 FPS and any other animation will be forced to run at the same rate when using CA to do UIView animation.  This question should be closed its by design.

Comment: I did not know about this and never saw it, can you please point me to the documentation that says this?  I looked on the UIView docs and google searched for "30 frames per second UIView" but nothing came up.

Comment: I havent worked on iOS games in a while, but its there. You cant mix UIView animation with anything open GL and mix frame rates.  CA has one renderer, and UIView animation clips it at 30fps.

Comment: I can't tell if you're trolling or not but your profile history suggests you might be.  Your answer is what I describe the problem as, and you say 'docs clearly state' without being able to link to the documentation.

Comment: Core Animation most definitely runs at 60 frames per second. Nothing in the OS would look smooth if it ran at 30 fps.